# Why does a containing div not expand to contain its content?

Tags: html, css

I have a series of divs inside one another. The innermost div contains a table. The parent divs do not expand to fit the table inside them. So if I set a background-color on body, the overflowing part of the table disappears under the background colour.

I don't understand why, or how to make div#datatableform_wrapper expand to fit table#datatableform inside it.

In the code below, if you remove background-color in body, you can see the whole table by scrolling.

The black background colour for everything outside the content included in the example is important to our designer (in the real site, there is other stuff below the main element).

```html
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body style="background-color: black">
    <main style="background-color: white;">
        <div id="body" style="overflow:visible;">
            <div id="datatableform_wrapper">
                <table id="datatableform" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width: 100%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 270px;">Col 1</th>
                            <th style="width: 92px;">Col 2</th>
                            <th style="width: 65px;">Col 3</th>
                            <th style="width: 217px;">Col 4</th>
                            <th style="width: 92px;">Col 5</th>
                            <th style="width: 129px;">Col 6</th>
                            <th style="width: 204px;">Col 7</th>
                            <th style="width: 89px;">Col 8</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>@0ESkKkGPiO8Yaj6hYEZIZ+C60wY@0ESkKkGPiO8Yaj6hYEZIZ+C60wY</td>
                            <td>@0ESkKkGPiO8Yaj6hYEZIZ+C60wY</td>
                            <td>@0ESkKkGPiO8Yaj6hYEZIZ+C60wY</td>
                            <td>0ESkKkGPiO8Yaj6hYEZIZ+C60wY@0ESkKkGPiO8Yaj6hYEZIZ+C60wY</td>
                            <td>@0ESkKkGPiO8Yaj6hYEZIZ+C60wY</td>
                            <td>@0ESkKkGPiO8Yaj6hYEZIZ+C60wY</td>
                            <td>ebyz776mhjg1fxdwduibhc95gr@0ESkKkGPiO8Yaj6hYEZIZ+C60wY</td>
                            <td>05 June 2020</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: display:inline-block to main

Comment: Utterly brilliant! How about posting that as an answer, so I can accept it? And, if you could explain why, that would be even more brilliant.

Comment: you can find all the detail in the duplicate, I already answered there